# How to convert IP4 and IP6 addresses to long value in C?

Tags: c, sockets, ip, ip-address

I need a function that works both with IP4 and IP6 addresses and I need to convert an address from it's string representation (IP4) or hexdecimal representation (IP6) to it's long value. The current code I have is:

```
struct addrinfo *addr;
// This converts an char* ip_address to an addrinfo, so now I know whether 
// it's a IP4 or IP6 address
int result = getaddrinfo(ip_address, NULL, NULL, &addr);
if (result ==0) {
    struct in_addr dst;
    result = inet_pton(addr->ai_family, ip_address, &dst);
    long ip_value = dst->s_addr;
    freeaddrinfo(addr);
    return ip_value;
}
```

I do get a long from dst->s_addr but I am pretty sure that this is incorrect. Any pointers on how to solve this are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `dst` isn't large enough for an `IPv6` address:

```
unsigned char buf[sizeof(struct in6_addr)]; /* Since it's larger than in_addr */
int result = getaddrinfo(ip_address, NULL, NULL, buf);
```

If the address is IPv4, `buf` is an `in_addr` which is an `uint32_t`.

```
uint32_t u;
memcpy(&u, buf, sizeof(u));
```

If the address is IPv6 converting to *`long`* doesn't actually make sense. You need something that's `128` bits wide or roll your own. That last bit isn't so easy, so ask yourself: are you sure you *need* this ?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help! When you say my inet_pton call is wrong, you mean the getaddrinfo call? About IP6, yes it should be a 128 bits, I know that we will need this so I rather fix it now.... Do I need to fix the inet_pton call as well?

Comment: @DrDee Sorry, I misread the question. Your `inet_pton` call is actually almost correct, I edited my answer.

Comment: The value that is in buf is always 140734799738144 (I guess that's sizeof struct in6_addr). Sorry for keep  asking but how do I get from here the 'long' representation of the ip address?

Comment: @DrDee `in6_addr` is much larger (`2^128`). I don't know any way to get a decimal representation for a 128 bit number other than doing it by hand.